# Select updated rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is there simple way to select updated rows?

I'm trying to store timestamp each time I am read row to be able to delete data that was not readed for a long time.

First I tried execute `SELECT` query first and even found little bit slow but simple solution like

```
 UPDATE foo AS t, (SELECT id FROM foo WHERE statement=1)q
 SET t.time=NOW() WHERE t.id=q.id
```

but I still want to find a normal way to do this.

I also think that updating time first and then just select updated rows should be much easier, but I didn't find anything even for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the `time` column as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    ...
    time TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
    ...)
```

Then whenever a row is updated, the column will be updated automatically.

UPDATE:

I don't think there's a way to update automatically during SELECT, so you have to do it in two steps:

```
UPDATE foo
SET time = NOW()
WHERE <conditions>;

SELECT <columns>
FROM foo
WHERE <conditions>;
```

As long as  doesn't include the `time` column I think this should work. For maximum safety you'll need to use a transaction to prevent other queries from interfering.

Comment: I think your title is misleading. You want to update selected rows, not select updated rows. Anyway, see my updated answer.

Comment: Order doesn't matter. I thought it should be a better solution then two times execute practically the same query. But you seems to be right

Comment: You can define an on update in the table definition without using a trigger? Did not know this.

Comment: @Scotch Only for the special case of updating a TIMESTAMP column with the current time. For anything else you have to use a trigger.

Comment: Interesting, is this true with other RDBMS's?

Comment: @barmar I'll look it up myself:) +1 for you though

Answer (score 4):

For a *single-row* `UPDATE` in MySQL you could:

```
UPDATE foo
SET    time = NOW()
WHERE  statement = 1
AND    @var := id
```

`@var := id` is always `TRUE`, but it writes the value of `id` to the variable @var *before* the update. Then you can:

```
SELECT @var;
```

In *PostgreSQL* you could use the [`RETURNING` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html).
*Oracle* also has a [`RETURNING` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10008.htm#i2126358).
*SQL-Server* has an [`OUTPUT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).
But MySQL doesn't have anything like that.

Comment: No, it will return ~50 values.  
Don't really want to change database because of such a simple thing

Answer (score 1):

@Erwin Brandstetter: Not difficult to extend the strategy of using user variables with `CONCAT_WS()` to get back multiple IDs.  *Sorry, still can't add comments...*

Comment: I'm not really good at sql, how can I get back ids from result string?

Comment: Depends on your actual UPDATE statement; but something along the lines of (re-)setting a known user variable within the query, appending each ID to the variable, and then retrieving it thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55077611/7149182) you can extract the modified primary keys to update their timestamp column afterwards.

> ```
> SET @uids := null;
> UPDATE footable
>    SET foo = 'bar'
>  WHERE fooid > 5
>    AND ( SELECT @uids := CONCAT_WS(',', fooid, @uids) );
> SELECT @uids;
> ```
>
> from https://gist.github.com/PieterScheffers/189cad9510d304118c33135965e9cddb

So you should replace the final `SELECT @uids;` with an update statement by splitting the resulting `@uids` value (it will be a varchar containing all the modified ids divided by `,`).