# MySQL to return updated value(s)

Tags: mysql

When updating an explicit row in MySQL is there anyway to get the `UPDATE` query to return the value(s) that was actually updated?

```
+----+-------+---------------------+
| id | name  | last_changed_values |
+----+-------+---------------------+
|  1 | Hans  | (null)              |
|  2 | Joe   | (null)              |
|  3 | Ralph | (null)              |
+----+-------+---------------------+
```

`UPDATE user SET user_name = "Bertil" WHERE user_id = 1` would enter  `Bertil`
in `last_changed_values`

```
+----+-------+---------------------+
| id | name  | last_changed_values |
+----+-------+---------------------+
|  1 | Bertil| Bertil              |
|  2 | Joe   | (null)              |
|  3 | Ralph | (null)              |
+----+-------+---------------------+
```

With the help of GaborSch I've created this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bcbab/1).

```
CREATE TRIGGER names_BU BEFORE UPDATE ON `names`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN      
SET NEW.last_changed_values = CONCAT_WS(',', IF(new.name = old.name, NULL, new.name));  
END/
```

But this doesn't `SET` `last_changed_values` to `new.name` (in this case `Bertil`). Is there some way of picking up the new value?

**Update**
Seems like the stored procedure was case sensitive. Changed to

```
SET NEW.last_changed_values = CONCAT_WS(',', IF(NEW.name = OLD.name, NULL, NEW.name));
```

Works as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477121/mysql-return-updated-rows

Comment: you usually explicitly pass them to the update query. you already know them.

Comment: @newtover yes I know the values I'm passing but I don't know the values that are already present in the row.

Comment: MySQL has one `UPDATE` statement. Only the dataset will determine whether you update zero, one, or more rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no such option in MySQL. Remember, that an update can change several rows with one instruction.

However, you can create a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, and compare the values one-by-one, and save the changed column names to a `last_changed_values` column, something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN last_changed_values VARCHAR(200);

DELIMITER $$    
CREATE TRIGGER `mytable_BU` BEFORE UPDATE ON `mytable`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN      
    SET NEW.last_changed_values = CONCAT_WS(',', IF(new.col1 = old.col1, NULL, 'col1'), IF(new.col2 = old.col2, NULL, 'col2'), IF(new.col3 = old.col3, NULL, 'col3'));  
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

If you execute a statement like

```
UPDATE mytable SET col1=..., col2=...
WHERE id=1;
```

then you can query it like

```
SELECT last_changed_values FROM mytable 
WHERE id=1;
```

Comment: When `SET`ing `NEW.last_changed_values` is it possible to `SET` it to the `new.col1` value rather then just the column name (`col1`)?

Comment: Sure, it is possibe. It was just an example.

Comment: In the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bcbab/1) tried with `SET NEW.last_changed_values = CONCAT_WS(',', IF(new.name = old.name, NULL, new.name));` but `new.name` returns nothing/empty.

Comment: In the sqlfiddle the row #1 already contains 'Hans' as `name`. Try to update it to 'Peter', and you will see it working.