# jdbi returns 0 in @GetGeneratedKeys in update

Tags: java, dropwizard, jdbi

I have made dropwizzard application using jdbi2. I am doing an update on my table and have annotated the dao method which does this with @GetGeneratedKeys and return type int. The documentation [here](http://jdbi.org/jdbi2/sql_object_api_dml/) says

> If the return type is int, then the value will be the number of rows changed. Alternatively, if the method is annotated with @GetGeneratedKeys, then the return value with be the auto-generated keys.
> The insert method returns me correct 'id'.
> But my dao update method always returns me 0. Is there anything wrong here?

Here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`FIRSTNAME` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`LASTNAME` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is my POJO

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @JsonProperty
    private int id;
    @JsonProperty
    private String firstName;
    @JsonProperty
    private String lastName;
}
```

Here is my dao class with dao method to update

```
@RegisterMapper(UserMapper.class)
public interface UserDao  {

    @SqlUpdate("Insert into User (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) values (:firstName, :lastName)")
    @GetGeneratedKeys
    int insert(@BindBean User user); //returns correct autogenerated id

    @SqlUpdate("Update User set FIRSTNAME = :firstName," +
            "LASTNAME = :lastName where ID = :id")
    @GetGeneratedKeys
    int update(@BindBean User User); //Shouldn't it return the id of updated user?
}
```

And here is my resource class:

```
@Path("/user")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class UserResource {

    UserDao dao;

    public UserResource(UserDao UserDao)
    {
        this.dao = UserDao;
    }

    @POST
    public User add(@Valid User user) {
        int i = dao.insert(user); //returns correct autogenerated id
        user.setId(i);
        return user;
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/{id}")
    public User update(@PathParam("id") Integer id, @Valid User user) {
        User updateUser = new User(id, user.getFirstName(),user.getLastName());
        int i = dao.update(updateUser); // --> i is always 0, why?
        System.out.println(i);
        return updateUser;
    }

}
```

I am sending request using postman in this way:

```
Put:  localhost:7466/user/5
Body:(JSON/application/json) {
"firstName": "new_first_name",
"lastName": "new_last_name"
}
```

Please comment if anything is not clear. TIA 
EDIT : Shouldn't I get at least the number of rows updated here? I am getting 0 always.

Comment: I am using mysql database.

Comment: Jdbi project member here. Strictly speaking, no keys are being generated in your update. It also depends on how mysql behaves for updates--you might need a `RETURNING ID` clause.

Comment: It's also possible that no rows are being returned because your change wouldn't modify anything. Try changing int to Integer and see if it returns null instead.

Comment: @qualidafial  I changed "int update(...)" to "Integer update(...)" in my dao class, (and changed "int i" in resource class to "Integer i"), but it didn't make any difference. While debugging, i values comes as null.

Comment: @qualidafial Can you elaborate more on  `RETURNING ID` ? When I run an update query in the db directly, I get 'No errors; 1 row affected.'

Comment: I use PostgreSQL, not MySQL, so I'm not confident that you can use `@GetGeneratedKeys` to do this with MySQL. Looking around on StackOverflow, most of the answers I see suggest that you cannot return a value from the updated row if it wasn't generated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477121/mysql-return-updated-rows.

Comment: In your case, the insert statement is generating the ID (from the auto-increment counter), whereas the update statement is just updating a row based on the ID--you're not actually generating keys in the latter case.

Comment: @qualidafial I checked other answers on SO on how to return a value for `Update` query. At present, this is working for me: 
    `@SqlUpdate("Update User set FIRSTNAME = :firstName," +`
         `"LASTNAME = :lastName where ID = :id and last_insert_id(ID)")`
    `@GetGeneratedKeys`
    `int update(@BindBean User User);`

Comment: @qualidafial Shouldn't I at least get the number of rows updated without modifying my query?

Comment: If you exclude the `@GetGeneratedKeys` annotation, you should get the update count.