# return updated rows using mysql/nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

Using mysql end nodejs , how can I get the entire updated rows ?

```
var query2 = connection.query('UPDATE campaigns SET USED=0 where amount=?' , [amount], function (error, results, fields) {
                console.log(query2.sql);
                if (error) throw error;

// Get here all updated rows

}
```

With affectedRows, I can get only the number of updated rows.

Answer (score 0):

you can select all row's ids before update, then update them and then select them by ids

1st step: `select id from campaigns where amount=?`

2nd step: `update campaigns set USED=0 where amount=?`

3d step: `select * from campaigns where id in (<ids from 1st step>)`

Comment: there is no other way to avoid this first query ?

Comment: found similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477121/mysql-return-updated-rows